# Materialize CSS Select Dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, materialize

I am using Materialize CSS for my application,using media queries i am making my queries responsive.Select Dropdown we are not able to select any option,in laptop it is working fine but in tablet and mobile view it is not working..Can anyone help?

```
<div class="input-field col s12 newid m6 l6">
   <select>
           <option value="" disabled selected>All</option> 
           <option value="1">Option 1</option>
           <option value="2">Option 2</option> 
           <option value="3">Option 3</option> 
  </select>
  <label>Data</label>
```

```
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) { 
  .newid { width: 96%!important;
           margin-top: 8%!important;
           margin-left: 0%!important; 
         }
 }
```

Comment: This question has severe formatting or content problems. This question is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.

Comment: Please provide some code and maybe also on what devices you are testing it.

Comment: You should give more detail about your question. please read this article about how asking questions in stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can use https://jsfiddle.net to give demo of you code

Comment: can u fiddle your code here

Answer (score 1):

> I think you have missed to initialization for select to your
>   javaScript. You can try this for your Select Option Using Materialize
>   css.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').formSelect();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
<h5>materialize Select Option. </h5>

<div class="input-field">
    <select>
      <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
      <option value="1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you initialize the dropdown menu in your JavaScript? Many of the components that are part of *Materialize CSS* have to be initialized in order to function on the web page?

The code should be something like this

```
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('select');
var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems, options);
});
```